# Datalist RepeatColumns with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to mimic the RepeatColumn function of the ASP.NET DataList control in ASP.NET MVC. The goal is to have 2 or more rows of a collection in one table row.

The following code works, but it looks very ugly to me. Is there better way to do it? Thanks for any help!

```
<table>
    <% 
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
    {
    %>
    <tr>
        <% for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
           {
               if (i + j < items.Count())
               {
                   var item = items[i + j];
                   %>
                   <td>
                   <% Html.Encode(item.title) %>
                   </td>
                   <%
               }
               else 
               {
                %>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <%
               }
           }%>            
    </tr>
    <%} %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [DataList helper](http://code.google.com/p/mvccontrib/source/browse/trunk/src/MVCContrib/UI/DataList/) in [MVCContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib).

Answer (score 0):

try using datalist control.

... your data goes here. <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductName")%>